# Displaying JSON Weather API Response in PHP

Tags: arrays, json, weather-api

After looking through so many other questions here I'm still stuck with this. First I've never used JSON data ever before and am finding what should be rather simple to be rather tricky.

I have a JSON response like this from the DarkSky Weather API

```
{
    "latitude": -26.202271,
    "longitude": 28.043631,
    "timezone": "Africa\/Johannesburg",
    "daily": {
        "summary": "Light rain throughout the week, with high temperatures peaking at 28\u00b0C on Saturday.",
        "icon": "rain",
        "data": [
            {
                "time": 1549317600,
                "summary": "Mostly cloudy throughout the day.",
                "icon": "partly-cloudy-day",
                "sunriseTime": 1549338410,
                "sunsetTime": 1549385960,
                "moonPhase": 0.02,
                "precipIntensity": 0.0737,
                "precipIntensityMax": 0.6121,
                "precipIntensityMaxTime": 1549368000,
                "precipProbability": 0.14,
                "precipType": "rain",
                "temperatureHigh": 22.68,
                "temperatureHighTime": 1549364400,
                "temperatureLow": 15.14,
                "temperatureLowTime": 1549422000,
                "apparentTemperatureHigh": 22.68,
                "apparentTemperatureHighTime": 1549364400,
                "apparentTemperatureLow": 15.14,
                "apparentTemperatureLowTime": 1549422000,
                "dewPoint": 13.85,
                "humidity": 0.74,
                "pressure": 1015.08,
                "windSpeed": 1.84,
                "windGust": 7.01,
                "windGustTime": 1549342800,
                "windBearing": 40,
                "cloudCover": 0.73,
                "uvIndex": 8,
                "uvIndexTime": 1549357200,
                "visibility": 14.03,
                "ozone": 263.92,
                "temperatureMin": 15.02,
                "temperatureMinTime": 1549339200,
                "temperatureMax": 22.68,
                "temperatureMaxTime": 1549364400,
                "apparentTemperatureMin": 15.02,
                "apparentTemperatureMinTime": 1549339200,
                "apparentTemperatureMax": 22.68,
                "apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1549364400
            },
            {
                "time": 1549404000,
                "summary": "Mostly cloudy throughout the day.",
                "icon": "partly-cloudy-day",
                "sunriseTime": 1549424856,
                "sunsetTime": 1549472325,
                "moonPhase": 0.05,
                "precipIntensity": 0.0432,
                "precipIntensityMax": 0.2819,
                "precipIntensityMaxTime": 1549454400,
                "precipProbability": 0.13,
                "precipType": "rain",
                "temperatureHigh": 24.32,
                "temperatureHighTime": 1549454400,
                "temperatureLow": 15.83,
                "temperatureLowTime": 1549508400,
                "apparentTemperatureHigh": 24.32,
                "apparentTemperatureHighTime": 1549454400,
                "apparentTemperatureLow": 15.83,
                "apparentTemperatureLowTime": 1549508400,
                "dewPoint": 13.06,
                "humidity": 0.67,
                "pressure": 1013.86,
                "windSpeed": 1.34,
                "windGust": 6.01,
                "windGustTime": 1549414800,
                "windBearing": 341,
                "cloudCover": 0.71,
                "uvIndex": 8,
                "uvIndexTime": 1549443600,
                "visibility": 16.09,
                "ozone": 258.39,
                "temperatureMin": 15.14,
                "temperatureMinTime": 1549422000,
                "temperatureMax": 24.32,
                "temperatureMaxTime": 1549454400,
                "apparentTemperatureMin": 15.14,
                "apparentTemperatureMinTime": 1549422000,
                "apparentTemperatureMax": 24.32,
                "apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1549454400
            },
            {
                "time": 1549490400,
                "summary": "Light rain overnight.",
                "icon": "rain",
                "sunriseTime": 1549511300,
                "sunsetTime": 1549558690,
                "moonPhase": 0.08,
                "precipIntensity": 0.16,
                "precipIntensityMax": 0.6096,
                "precipIntensityMaxTime": 1549573200,
                "precipProbability": 0.23,
                "precipType": "rain",
                "temperatureHigh": 25.43,
                "temperatureHighTime": 1549540800,
                "temperatureLow": 16.47,
                "temperatureLowTime": 1549591200,
                "apparentTemperatureHigh": 25.43,
                "apparentTemperatureHighTime": 1549540800,
                "apparentTemperatureLow": 16.61,
                "apparentTemperatureLowTime": 1549591200,
                "dewPoint": 14.17,
                "humidity": 0.69,
                "pressure": 1013.06,
                "windSpeed": 2.28,
                "windGust": 7.57,
                "windGustTime": 1549497600,
                "windBearing": 342,
                "cloudCover": 0.52,
                "uvIndex": 12,
                "uvIndexTime": 1549533600,
                "visibility": 16.09,
                "ozone": 251.95,
                "temperatureMin": 15.83,
                "temperatureMinTime": 1549508400,
                "temperatureMax": 25.43,
                "temperatureMaxTime": 1549540800,
                "apparentTemperatureMin": 15.83,
                "apparentTemperatureMinTime": 1549508400,
                "apparentTemperatureMax": 25.43,
                "apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1549540800
            },
            {
                "time": 1549576800,
                "summary": "Mostly cloudy throughout the day.",
                "icon": "partly-cloudy-day",
                "sunriseTime": 1549597745,
                "sunsetTime": 1549645053,
                "moonPhase": 0.11,
                "precipIntensity": 0.2819,
                "precipIntensityMax": 1.1481,
                "precipIntensityMaxTime": 1549584000,
                "precipProbability": 0.39,
                "precipType": "rain",
                "temperatureHigh": 25.17,
                "temperatureHighTime": 1549627200,
                "temperatureLow": 16.64,
                "temperatureLowTime": 1549677600,
                "apparentTemperatureHigh": 25.19,
                "apparentTemperatureHighTime": 1549627200,
                "apparentTemperatureLow": 16.64,
                "apparentTemperatureLowTime": 1549677600,
                "dewPoint": 15.46,
                "humidity": 0.77,
                "pressure": 1013.3,
                "windSpeed": 1.21,
                "windGust": 5.91,
                "windGustTime": 1549580400,
                "windBearing": 310,
                "cloudCover": 0.91,
                "uvIndex": 7,
                "uvIndexTime": 1549616400,
                "visibility": 16.09,
                "ozone": 249.44,
                "temperatureMin": 16.47,
                "temperatureMinTime": 1549591200,
                "temperatureMax": 25.17,
                "temperatureMaxTime": 1549627200,
                "apparentTemperatureMin": 16.61,
                "apparentTemperatureMinTime": 1549591200,
                "apparentTemperatureMax": 25.19,
                "apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1549627200
            },
            {
                "time": 1549663200,
                "summary": "Rain overnight.",
                "icon": "rain",
                "sunriseTime": 1549684188,
                "sunsetTime": 1549731414,
                "moonPhase": 0.14,
                "precipIntensity": 0.221,
                "precipIntensityMax": 0.7645,
                "precipIntensityMaxTime": 1549670400,
                "precipProbability": 0.27,
                "precipType": "rain",
                "temperatureHigh": 27.92,
                "temperatureHighTime": 1549713600,
                "temperatureLow": 16.84,
                "temperatureLowTime": 1549760400,
                "apparentTemperatureHigh": 27.92,
                "apparentTemperatureHighTime": 1549713600,
                "apparentTemperatureLow": 16.93,
                "apparentTemperatureLowTime": 1549760400,
                "dewPoint": 14.08,
                "humidity": 0.67,
                "pressure": 1011.76,
                "windSpeed": 0.19,
                "windGust": 6.53,
                "windGustTime": 1549688400,
                "windBearing": 145,
                "cloudCover": 0.94,
                "uvIndex": 7,
                "uvIndexTime": 1549702800,
                "visibility": 16.09,
                "ozone": 253.47,
                "temperatureMin": 16.64,
                "temperatureMinTime": 1549677600,
                "temperatureMax": 27.92,
                "temperatureMaxTime": 1549713600,
                "apparentTemperatureMin": 16.64,
                "apparentTemperatureMinTime": 1549677600,
                "apparentTemperatureMax": 27.92,
                "apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1549713600
            },
            {
                "time": 1549749600,
                "summary": "Rain in the morning.",
                "icon": "rain",
                "sunriseTime": 1549770632,
                "sunsetTime": 1549817775,
                "moonPhase": 0.17,
                "precipIntensity": 1.0668,
                "precipIntensityMax": 4.2316,
                "precipIntensityMaxTime": 1549760400,
                "precipProbability": 0.43,
                "precipType": "rain",
                "temperatureHigh": 24.07,
                "temperatureHighTime": 1549803600,
                "temperatureLow": 17.25,
                "temperatureLowTime": 1549854000,
                "apparentTemperatureHigh": 24.07,
                "apparentTemperatureHighTime": 1549803600,
                "apparentTemperatureLow": 17.25,
                "apparentTemperatureLowTime": 1549854000,
                "dewPoint": 14.73,
                "humidity": 0.72,
                "pressure": 1011.87,
                "windSpeed": 2.52,
                "windGust": 7.58,
                "windGustTime": 1549778400,
                "windBearing": 358,
                "cloudCover": 0.72,
                "uvIndex": 14,
                "uvIndexTime": 1549792800,
                "visibility": 15.58,
                "ozone": 257.27,
                "temperatureMin": 16.84,
                "temperatureMinTime": 1549760400,
                "temperatureMax": 24.07,
                "temperatureMaxTime": 1549803600,
                "apparentTemperatureMin": 16.93,
                "apparentTemperatureMinTime": 1549760400,
                "apparentTemperatureMax": 24.07,
                "apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1549803600
            },
            {
                "time": 1549836000,
                "summary": "Mostly cloudy starting in the afternoon.",
                "icon": "partly-cloudy-night",
                "sunriseTime": 1549857075,
                "sunsetTime": 1549904134,
                "moonPhase": 0.2,
                "precipIntensity": 0.0381,
                "precipIntensityMax": 0.2489,
                "precipIntensityMaxTime": 1549886400,
                "precipProbability": 0.13,
                "precipType": "rain",
                "temperatureHigh": 26.19,
                "temperatureHighTime": 1549890000,
                "temperatureLow": 15.78,
                "temperatureLowTime": 1549944000,
                "apparentTemperatureHigh": 26.19,
                "apparentTemperatureHighTime": 1549890000,
                "apparentTemperatureLow": 15.78,
                "apparentTemperatureLowTime": 1549944000,
                "dewPoint": 12.99,
                "humidity": 0.61,
                "pressure": 1008.71,
                "windSpeed": 2.54,
                "windGust": 8.12,
                "windGustTime": 1549857600,
                "windBearing": 326,
                "cloudCover": 0.47,
                "uvIndex": 15,
                "uvIndexTime": 1549879200,
                "visibility": 16.09,
                "ozone": 246.75,
                "temperatureMin": 17.25,
                "temperatureMinTime": 1549854000,
                "temperatureMax": 26.19,
                "temperatureMaxTime": 1549890000,
                "apparentTemperatureMin": 17.25,
                "apparentTemperatureMinTime": 1549854000,
                "apparentTemperatureMax": 26.19,
                "apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1549890000
            },
            {
                "time": 1549922400,
                "summary": "Rain in the afternoon.",
                "icon": "rain",
                "sunriseTime": 1549943518,
                "sunsetTime": 1549990493,
                "moonPhase": 0.24,
                "precipIntensity": 0.3912,
                "precipIntensityMax": 1.6332,
                "precipIntensityMaxTime": 1549972800,
                "precipProbability": 0.48,
                "precipType": "rain",
                "temperatureHigh": 22.24,
                "temperatureHighTime": 1549983600,
                "temperatureLow": 16.23,
                "temperatureLowTime": 1550030400,
                "apparentTemperatureHigh": 22.24,
                "apparentTemperatureHighTime": 1549983600,
                "apparentTemperatureLow": 16.23,
                "apparentTemperatureLowTime": 1550030400,
                "dewPoint": 13.89,
                "humidity": 0.72,
                "pressure": 1008.8,
                "windSpeed": 1.88,
                "windGust": 8.13,
                "windGustTime": 1549972800,
                "windBearing": 1,
                "cloudCover": 0.94,
                "uvIndex": 6,
                "uvIndexTime": 1549958400,
                "visibility": 16.09,
                "ozone": 244.47,
                "temperatureMin": 15.78,
                "temperatureMinTime": 1549944000,
                "temperatureMax": 22.24,
                "temperatureMaxTime": 1549983600,
                "apparentTemperatureMin": 15.78,
                "apparentTemperatureMinTime": 1549944000,
                "apparentTemperatureMax": 22.24,
                "apparentTemperatureMaxTime": 1549983600
            }
        ]
    },
    "offset": 2
}
```

What I am trying to achieve now is to extract the temperatureHigh and temperatureLow for the next 5 days excluding today or yesterday.

Based on the above code being fresh from today 2019-02-05 the first two days need to be excluded. So I want to start the forecast data I extract from the timestamp `1549490400`

What I would like to end up with is the following display of echoed data.

```
Johannesburg
Wednesday [weathericon] MAX: `temperatureHigh` °C LOW: `temperatureLow` °C
Thursday [weathericon] MAX: `temperatureHigh` °C LOW: `temperatureLow` °C
Friday [weathericon] MAX: `temperatureHigh` °C LOW: `temperatureLow` °C
Saturday [weathericon] MAX: `temperatureHigh` °C LOW: `temperatureLow` °C
Sunday [weathericon] MAX: `temperatureHigh` °C LOW: `temperatureLow` °C
Monday [weathericon] MAX: `temperatureHigh` °C LOW: `temperatureLow` °C
```

I would also like to perhaps do only a 3-day forecast like this

```
Johannesburg
Wednesday [weathericon] MAX: `temperatureHigh` °C LOW: `temperatureLow` °C
Thursday [weathericon] MAX: `temperatureHigh` °C LOW: `temperatureLow` °C
Friday [weathericon] MAX: `temperatureHigh` °C LOW: `temperatureLow` °C
```

Where I say [weathericon] I need to pull the `"icon": "rain"` for example from each day and match it with a locally stored .jpg / .png with the same name. ie. rain.png or rain.jpg

I have tried various loops, foreach examples on other answers here but nothing seems to get me to display the data properly.

Here's something I got partially working but due to my lack of understanding of JSON not sure why I am getting all the blank rows.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$json_string = file_get_contents("https://api.darksky.net/forecast/MYAPIKEY/-26.202271,28.043631?exclude=[currently,minutely,hourly,alerts,flags]&units=si");
$jsondata = json_decode($json_string, true);
//Echo Data
foreach ($jsondata as $max) {
  echo "MAX: ".$max['data'][2]['temperatureHigh']."\n";
  echo "MAX: ".$max['data'][3]['temperatureHigh']."\n";
  echo "MAX: ".$max['data'][4]['temperatureHigh']."\n";
}
?>
```

The above gives me this output

```
MAX: 
MAX: 
MAX: 
MAX: 
MAX: 
MAX: 
MAX: 
MAX: 
MAX: 
MAX: 25.43
MAX: 25.17
MAX: 27.92
MAX: 
MAX: 
MAX:
```

Comment: if you know array structure and keys you need, why you are using foreach

Comment: I posted the foreach example above as that's the only snippet I found anywhere which displayed any data at all. I tried simple echo's like this `echo $jsonData['data'][2]['temperatureHigh']."<br/>";` but they just give me completely blank output, I also then tried like this `echo 'MAX: ' . $jsonData->data[2]->temperatureHigh;` but also no data displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the right array index. Go for:

```
foreach($jsondata['daily']['data'] as $dayData) {
    $dayData['temperatureHigh'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works great now to display all 8 days, how would I exclude the first two days?  Similarly how can I exclude first 2 and last 3 giving me a 3 day outlook for wednesday, thursday and friday only?

Comment: If the API sends days in fixed positions (1st is always Monday say, 3rd is Wednesday), I'd make array of indicies to skip.

foreach($jsondata['daily']['data'] as $dayIndex => $dayData) {
    if(!in_array($dayIndex,$arrayOfDaysToSkip,true)) {
        processDay();
    }
}

Comment: $arrayOfDaysToSkip = [0,1,5,6,7]; //Or something like that

Comment: The JSON response changes (I think) every day unfortunately so tomorrow day [2] would become Thursday. I'll have to double check that tomorrow

Comment: You can always parse that $dayData['time'] into \DateTime and go from there

Comment: Is there no way to simply echo individual items as in my comment reply to Zeljka ?

Comment: Yes, you probably could, but there will be issue if you would like to work with the data further. Accessing array indexes like this could lead errors in future but it will sure work for now

Comment: Thanks for my current application it might just work, not ideal and I agree at a later point with anything complex it would lead to errors. My only issue is getting my syntax correct. I have tried things like `echo "MAX:" . $jsonData['data'][2]['temperatureHigh']."<br/>";` but no result, also tried using the correct array which you pointed out like this `echo "MAX: " . $jsonData->daily->data[1]->temperatureHigh . "";` above but still get no data displayed. I just know I am doing something chronically stupid.

Comment: Are you sure you tried: $jsonData['daily']['data'][2]['temperatureHigh'] ? (watch the daily index)

Comment: Indeed `echo "TEST: " . $jsonData['daily']['data'][2]['temperatureHigh'] . "";` and I get this back `TEST: ` this is why I am totally stumped.

Comment: Weird, try `var_dump($jsonData['daily']['data'])` and check if there is index 2 present with expected data. Also make sure you have error reporting enabled

Comment: I told you I was doing something chronically stupid ... on those two tests printing individual items I had `$jsonData` instead of `$jsondata` I am smacking my head as I type this

Comment: Oh dont worry its okay, hoping all goes smoother furher on

Comment: Thank so much for your help I truly appreciate it.